# What is the Include(..) method not getting found, on my IObjectSet object, in this Entity Framework code?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, eager-loading

i'm trying to eager load some child entity, and when I try to add the Include() method, i'm getting a compiler error (ie. it can't find it).

[alt text http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/5638/whatthec.png](http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/5638/whatthec.png)

er ... can anyone help me out on this one, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this post by Julie Lerman [Agile Entity Framework 4 Repository Part 5: IObjectSet and Include](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/agile-entity-framework-4-repository-part-5-iobjectset/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Include() is not a method of IObjectSet, not of any interface it extends:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642094(VS.100).aspx

`Include` is a member of ObjectQuery (it also returns a ObjectQuery), so you need a ObjectQuery object to start with.